# What if the Big Bang was an accident?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, explosions

Is it possible that the Big Bang was the product of a fission of an infinitesimal particle produced by an advanced civilization that destroyed part of the universe, and that there are other parts of the universe that we aren't able to perceive with our current instruments?

And maybe what we call "universe" is just the border of what we are able to see? And that the expansion of the "universe" is the movement of the particles affected by the expanding force of the explosion?

Comment: Try Worldbuilding.SE for science fiction scenarios.

Comment: This question is purely speculative and contains no actual physics.

Comment: define 'accident' . do you mean unplanned by a mind?

Answer (score 1):

These are certainly interesting ideas. But they are all speculation. They could be right, for all we know, but these are more questions for philosophy/religion than science.

I say this not because these are "bad" questions - they could be perfectly reasonable. But science is about looking at facts and developing a theory based on those facts. Right now, we don't understand stuff *in* our universe. We don't even really understand the Big Bang, let alone what (if anything) came before it, or what caused it. We have some guesses, but no evidence for (or against, really) any of them.

However, there are some things we can do. With these possibilities, we can look at their other implications and see if those implications make sense. We can learn about what we do know and use that to formulate reasoned guesses and theories. I would recommend reading about the thermodynamic arrow of time, what we do know about the beginning of the universe, and things along those lines. Specifically, I would recommend Stephen Hawking's books, Sean Carroll's *From Eternity to Here*, and other cosmology books.

If you wanted, you could also look into philosophy books and ideas (though be warned - philosophy has had a mighty hard time keeping up with new scientific discoveries) and religious ideas (there are several scientifically oriented Christian books, for example - *The Case for a Creator* by Lee Strobel might be an interesting one to read.

These are all just ideas, because we don't know. But keep reading, keep learning, and keep wondering. Hope this helps!

Comment: Speculations, not assumptions.  Assumptions are the starting points you use in reasoning towards a conclusion.  Here there are just the speculations (eg the catastrophic destruction of a former universe caused by an advanced civilization) and the conclusions (eg the Big Bang) with no reasoning in between.